# Show or open my plugin in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, popup-balloons

I'm developing a plugin for IntelliJ and the default state of the plugin is hide (like the others plugins - Maven Projects, Ant Build etc...)

My plugin uses the package com.intellij.openapi.ui.popup.BalloonBuilder to show a balloon on part of classes with some logic.

Now I want to add the functionality to show or open the plugin:

```
        builder.setClickHandler(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Show or open the plugin
            }
        }, true);
```

How I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is call to show method on ToolWindow object:

```
ToolWindow toolWindow = toolWindowManager.registerToolWindow("MyPlugin", myPanel, ToolWindowAnchor.RIGHT);

builder.setClickHandler(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            toolWindow.show(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.print("Showing the plugin!");
                        }
                });
        }
}, true);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code.